# Are Python PEPs public domain?

Tags: python, pep

I'm new to programming and was wondering if I would ever run into any copyright issues with PEPs and what the guidelines are with code and intellectual property.

Answer (score 3):

[PEP1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/):

> Copyright/public domain -- Each PEP must either be explicitly labeled
>   as placed in the public domain (see this PEP as an example) or
>   licensed under the Open Publication License [7].

i.e. an explicit statement is required for public domain; otherwise, recognition of a proposal as PEP requires OPL

Comment: Ok, awesome! Thanks!!